# Javascript string replace with dynamically created pattern

Tags: javascript, str-replace

My code only replaces the first match, ignoring the flags (global and multi line). What am I doing wrong?

```
for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        template = template.replace('{' + i + '}', values[i].toString().trim(), 'gm');
    }
```

As you can see, my placeholders have this format: {0}, {1} etc

Comment: Unless there's some new feature I don't know about, the `.replace()` method doesn't accept regex modifiers. Maybe you meant to use the `RegExp` constructor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), the flags are non-standard for the normal `.replace()` method. Instead, you can pass in a RegExp with the same result.

```
template.replace(new RegExp('\\{' + i + '\\}', 'gm'),
    values[i].toString().trim());
```

Since curly braces have special significance in regular expressions, you have to escape them.

Comment: Well, it turns out this RegEx doesn't work at all.

This string:


    <input type="text" name="Name" value="{1}" />

is returned as:



    <input type="text" name="Name" value />

Can anyone fix it? I think RegEx is evil myself, I hate it :-)

Comment: @TerjeHauger: I don't see how that's possible, the regex isn't even capturing `=` or `"`. What was the value of `values[i].toString()`?

Comment: `var test = "<label>Active:</label><input type="checkbox" name="Active"{10} />";
document.write(test.replace(new RegExp('\\{1\\}', 'gm'), ''));`

Output:

`<input type="checkbox" name="Active" =""="">`

Huh?!

Comment: Now I get it. This html: <.. name="Name"{0} /> is recognized as an html attribute, and at least in Chrome, {0}="" is added automagically. My idea was to insert 'checked="checked" based on passed value. I guess I should try a different template placeholder, <% %> will probably work.